# Para que serve o raw() na ncurses.h

Tags: c, c++, linux, ncurses

Recentemente estou tentando aprender mais sobre a biblioteca ncurses e me deparei com alguns codigos que usam

```
raw();
```

Quando eu tirei pra testar o'que acontecia, não mudou nada, o código compilou e funcionou perfeitamente. Então porque o raw() existe ? Para que ele serve ? qual a sua função ?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/raw

Comment: Já tinha visto esse site, e não entendi nada. Alguem pode me explicar de uma maneira mais simples ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As funções `raw()` e `noraw()` ativa e desativa o *raw mode* do terminal. Isto é, quando o terminal está em *raw mode* (podemos traduzir pra "modo cru", ou "modo sem processar"), caracteres digitados são passados para o programa rodando no terminal imediata e diretamente. Consequentemente, os caracteres de interrupção, fechamento, suspensão e controle de fluxo são todos passados, sem serem interpretados pelo terminal e gerar algum sinal.

Por exemplo, se abrirmos um programa que chama a função `raw()` e coloca o terminal em *raw mode* e apertássemos <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (significando o caractere de controle `^C`, que gera um sinal `SIGINT` pro programa rodando no terminal), não teríamos resposta alguma do terminal. Em vez de gerar o sinal de interrupção, o terminal passaria o caractere de controle `^C` direto pro programa, que por sua vez terá a possibilidade de lê-lo. Sem o *raw mode*, o terminal interpretaria o caractere `^C` e geraria um sinal de interrupção para o programa, que praticamente terminaria o programa.